# find distance of the element from the left

Tags: javascript, css

I have element centered in th middle of screen using trick e.g

```
.info{
    z-index: 0;
        width: 700px;
        height: 500px;
        margin: auto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
```

inside that element i have another element, how can i retrieve the distance of that element from upper left side? I have tried `offsetLeft` property but it returned 0 , due to trick i have mentioned that have all properties set on 0 , how can i overcome this?
html

```
<div class="info">

    <div class="vyrobky">
<div class="vyrobky_holder">
<ul>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
        <li>
            <div class="vyrobky_image"><img src="zabradlia/5.jpg" style="transform: scale(1);"></div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>

</div></div>
```

Comment: It's no quite clear.. could you add the HTML-Code please?

Answer (score 0):

Because you positioned the box with margin and set the `top`, `left`, `right`, `bottom` property to `0`, there won't be any distance between the box and it's parent.

But you can get the computed `margin` values which are refer to the space between the content and the parent element.

```
var el = document.querySelector('.info');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);

var top = style['margin-top'],
    left = style['margin-left'];

alert(
    "Top:" + top + '\n' +
    "Left:" + left
);
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/af746bdg/)**

Comment: alert(top) results in [Window][Object]

Comment: It works perfectly for me in the example: `https://jsfiddle.net/af746bdg/2/`. Of course you have to convert the pixel string value to a number!

Comment: yes i know , the left property is fine  but top always result in [window][Object] in my case

Comment: var el = document.querySelector('.info');
var style = window.getComputedStyle(el);

var top = style['margin-top'];
var left = style['margin-left'];
alert(top)           same cde as gabe posted.

Comment: Write `style['margin-top']` instead of `style['top']`. Because you in this case you aren't able to get the positioning properties, due to that they are set to zero! But the margin properties show the distance because you positioned the element with `margin` property!

Comment: seems like copied wrong code , it didnt work with margin-top either ,